# Can anybody explain this how it will work without duplicates & sorted order here?

Tags: java

I have list have duplicates data,i know that Set will not allow duplicates and LinkedHashSet will give sorting order,how internally it will do can anybody explain this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
 import java.util.List;

public class RemoveDuplicate {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> sourceList = new ArrayList<String>();

    sourceList.add("object1");
    sourceList.add("object2");
    sourceList.add("object2");
    sourceList.add("object3");
    sourceList.add("object4");
    sourceList.add("object2");

    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(
            sourceList));
    Iterator<String> it = newList.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }

   }
}
```

The above code displaying list without duplicates and have sorting order.
how internally LinkedHashSet will work can anybody explain this?

Comment: You might have a look into the source code to see for yourself.

Comment: A high level overview [on hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: You Set will use equals method to check for duplicates and comparable sort. You can find the java docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: if you see the source code implementation of `HashSet` you will find the values are stored in `HashMap<Key,value>`, here your set value is store as key in HashMap internally, and HashMap does not Allow Duplicate key so Set is allowing Unique Value, if we try to add duplicate it will be replaced with old one.

Comment: The code is not sorting the data, it is just keeping the first entry from each dupe, which in this case, happens to be sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LinkedHashSet` extended `HashSet`. See the HashSet source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java) and [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashSet.java.html)

> HashSet uses the internal map to store your value as key, and if key is already exist(means you value already in set) then the call leaves the set unchanged and returns `false`.

See the code below from `HashSet`:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have sorted order, because you adds your elements in sorted order and because duplicates are removed.

Your order is:

1. object1
2. object2
3. object2
4. object3
5. object4
6. object2

`LinkedHashSet` don't allow duplicates, so it's delete third object and sixth object and in result we have:

1. object1
2. object2
3. object3
4. object4

`LinkedHashSet` extends `HashSet` and using `HashMap` object to store values. If you want to understand how duplicates not added to `LinkedHashSet` you need to look into method `HashMap.putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent, boolean evict)`  but this method complicated(JDK version 1.8).

You can see the source code of this classes in your IDE if you downloaded jdk with source code.

Comment: ok Alexander,LinkedHashSet will not allow duplicates its ok,my doubt is how internally it works to remove duplicates

Comment: @vallepuveerendrakumar : see sumit's answer, HashSet will put value in map as a key. and map don't allow duplicate value. So, HashSet will not allow duplicate values.